# Como re-atribuir a colunda ID novamente?

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho uma tabela por exemplo

```
| ID  | NOME |
|  2  | Ana  |
|  7  | João |
|  15 | Vera |
```

A coluna ID é `ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`

**O que eu preciso obter?**

Eu pretendo que a coluna fique

```
| ID  | NOME |
|  1  | Ana  |
|  2  | João |
|  3  | Vera |
```

Eu tentei muitos exemplos um deles seria usar um php para re-atribuir a cada campo da coluna.

Não existe nenhuma forma de fazer isto com um comando SQL ?

Comment: É relativamente simples de fazer isso usando UPDATE com @variaveis e SET, mas provavelmente você está tentando resolver um [Problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499). Não quer especificar melhor sua necessidade para uma solução mais abrangente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você quer uma numeração sequencial, não precisa mudar os IDs, basta usar um contador:

```
SELECT    @linha := @linha + 1 AS contador,
          tabela_desejada.*
FROM      (SELECT @linha := 0) AS nada,
          tabela_desejada
ORDER BY  id;
```

Assim você terá a numeração sequencial.

Mas se realmente quiser mudar os IDs, pode usar a mesma lógica fazendo um UPDATE.

Entretanto, entendo que é uma solução péssima, e que vai dar manutenção desnecessária. O sentido do campo Id é ser a **Identidade** do registro, e não um contador de linhas. Se precisa de um contador sequencial, provavelmente deva usar um caminho como o sugerido acima, ou uma coluna separada para isto.

De qualquer forma, segue a *query*:

```
SET       @contador:=0;
UPDATE    tabela
SET       id=@contador:=@contador+1
ORDER BY  id;
```

e prepare-se para ficar consertando a autonumeração do DB em uma diversidade de ocasiões.